# Storyboard doesn't load (keep loading) Xamarin.ios VS 2017

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, visual-studio-2017

My storyboard file stopped showing, I tried:

1. Disconnect then reconnect to my Mac.
2. Clean and rebuild the project.
3. Restart both devices.

But nothing helped.

I am using VS pro 2017 - Xamarin 4.6.0.299 and Xamarin.IOS 10.12.0.20.
My Xamarin and Xcode in Mac are up to date.

I am using a powerful PC so I don't think my PC performance is the problem since before the problem I needed only 10 sec to show the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: What does the Output window say? it'll usually give you some indication of what the renderer is doing, or the mac agent for that matter.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt There is nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try opening the Storyboard source file, removing the device element at the top, then saving and reopening? Thank you!

As per the developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/89193/error-when-openning-ios-designer.html